# Action creator is not connected to redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using `redux-thunk` middleware (RactNative app). My action creators are used in several screens where they are working perfectly. But recently I have added a new screen which also uses those action creators. The problem is when I call them, they are not returning a `Promise` unlike in other screens. I attached `.then` callback to action creator which is throwing an error saying `.then is not a function`.

Here is my screen:

```
import ... ;
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  cancelAsync,
  acceptAsync
} from "../redux/actions";

function PreviewScreen(props) {
  const {
    ...
    acceptAsync,
    cancelAsync
  } = props;

  console.log(cancelAsync()); // returns function body: ƒ (dispatch, getState) { ...

  const accept = id => {
    acceptAsync(id).then(() => {...});
  };

  const cancel = id => {
    cancelAsync(id).then(() => {...});
  };

  return ...
}


const mapStateToProps = ... ;

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    dispatch,
    cancelAsync,
    acceptAsync
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PreviewScreen);
```

And these are my action creators:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  acceptURL,
  cancelURL,
} from "../../constants";

export const acceptAsync = id => {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const request = axios.post(
      acceptURL,
      { id },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token ${token}`
        }
      }
    );

    request
      .then(response => {
        ...
        return response;
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        ...
        return reason;
      });

    return request;
  };
};

export const cancelAsync = (orderID, status) => {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    const request = axios.post(
      cancelURL,
      {},
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token ${token}`
        }
      }
    );

    request
      .then(({ data }) => {
        ...
        return data;
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        ...
        return reason;
      });

    return request;
  };
};
```

What I might be missing? It's happening only on this screen.

A piece of code from another screen which is working correctly:

```
import {
  acceptOrderAsync,
  cancelOrderAsync,
  setNewOrdersAsync
} from "../redux/actions";

function NewOrdersScreen(props) {
  const {
    ...
    setNewOrdersAsync,
    acceptOrderAsync,
    cancelOrderAsync,
    navigation
  } = props;

  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ newOrders }) => ({ ...newOrders });

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { acceptOrderAsync, cancelOrderAsync, setNewOrdersAsync }
)(NewOrdersScreen);
```

Comment: Redux doesn't work with functions like this. You need to use class if you are using redux to dispatch an action/ or to map the state. Also, screens should be container and function should be component meaning, you should pass state(functions which dispatches actions) from screens to components

Comment: @iRohitBhatia but how we can explain that they are working in other functional components? As I understood what you are saying is I need to use either dispatch or action creator only, right?

Comment: I haven't seen your other functions and I could be wrong, but it looks like you are passing the actions as props `const {
    ...
    acceptAsync,
    cancelAsync
  } = props;` making this line probably uncessary -> `import {
  cancelAsync,
  acceptAsync
} from "../redux/actions";` Can you share code for your class component from where you are passing props and other functional component where it worked?

Comment: Actually I haven't used classes in this project as react introduced hooks. But anyways, I have updated the question

Comment: Geez! I haven't worked on react-hooks yet.

Comment: Damn. Now it is working after i have eliminated the dispatch function and left action creators only! Thank you @iRohitBhatia!